# select entrys with row count > 0 in other table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables users and items in a MySQL DB

```
Users
pk   username
1    John
2    Adam
3    Eve

Items
pk   user_pk    status
1    1          0
2    1          1
3    2          0
```

I want create a select that returns all users that have 1 or more items that have status>0.

In the case above I would like to return only John since he is the only one having an item with status 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT u.username
FROM users u INNER JOIN items it
    ON u.pk = it.user_pk
WHERE it.status > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Users.username FROM Users JOIN Items
ON Users.pk = Items.pk
WHERE Items.status>0
```

Comment: OP didn't ask, but probably it's better to use `DISTINCT` to get single users :)

Comment: I did not use DISTINCT because this way he can select others field and get them, example if he want to get username and all the items with count>0

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT `Users`.`username` 
    FROM `Users`, `Items` 
    WHERE `Items`.`status` > 0 
        AND `Users`.`pk` = `Item`.`user_pk`;
```

Comment: Explicit JOIN (see other answers) is better that implicit one ;)